# What can I put over my window wells to prevent leaves and trash from falling down into them?

Tags: windows, materials

What can I put over my window wells to prevent leaves and trash from falling down into them?

Comment: I would imagine mesh to catch/hold stuff more than a cover.

Comment: That's the kind of thing you would normally **purchase rolled up** and then you unroll it and cut to size.

Comment: A common solution is some sort of clear plastic - doesn't allow air (but usually not an issue for window wells) but allows light and blocks rain and junk.

Comment: If you want steel; look under a heading of "expanded metal".

Comment: There is a whole industry selling Window Well Covers.  You should enhance your question to describe why none of them are suitable.

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's illegal (and foolish) to block egress where that would cause a safety concern.

Comment: There used to be (or are?) commercially available window well covers made out of clear or translucent plastic. Haven't noticed them advertised in years, but they used to be popular.

Comment: Very sorry all. I don't know what happened but my question was rewritten by someone for some unknown reason and now it makes no sense and doesn't address the issue I was asking about.  Also, for some reason I am unable to delete my question now. Please delete this question if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Search the internet or your favorite local retailer for "window well cover".

You'll find a wide variety of clearish plastic ones that have various amounts of slope to them (thus helping leaves and other junk slide off, especially when it rains), to flat plastic grids that might be less ugly (in the eye of the beholder) that will be strong enough to support someone/thing (animals?) that may step on the otherwise flat looking surface.

IMHO, these would be much better than trying to make something of your own, especially if you have any animals or kids or there are any in your neighborhood. The designed covers will have the strength/shape to keep them from falling into the well, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a plastic mesh or plastic-coated mesh.  It comes in rolls and different mesh sizes.

Garden Centres and Handyman stores should stock them.

Image one range below, you can also get hexagonal patterns.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To keep stuff out of a window well, the only things that are coming to mind will require maintence as well. They would also require, like all infrastructure, repairs and replacement.  However I can imagine scenarios, sonme seasonal, where a shield of some sort would be less maintenance.  To me another downside of the things that come to mind is hampering / soiling the view, for example of the surrounding greenery and sky, as well as reduced sunlight.

Various freelists often have window screens and sash, as well as hardware cloth, chicken wire and the like.  For example if you window well is 36"x16", then a 2'x4' skylight sash leaned against the wall might satisfy your needs.

You could also by a small sheet of ridgid plastic cut to your size at the store (or use a utility knife to score & snap), drive two stakes into the ground about 20" from the wall, attach one or another kind of knuckle near the top of the stakes, then set the plastic on top of the knuckles and let the plastic lay back against the wall.

Hardware cloth, used or new, can be easily bent / re-flattened without tools, so could bent into a cage to place freestanding over the well.  In this case some of the bends will likely be back onto themselves to form the odd end shapes. The cage could be similar, but made with each face a separate piece, all hinged together by small zipties to make it easily storeable seasonally or as needed.

If a cage has too much project in it, then a 2'x4' flat sheet duct taped on one edge and leaned against the building might suffice.